# Convert array into comma separated strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have array like this 
`var array =["123", "456", "789"]`

How do I convert this into `var string = "123", "456", "789"`

I tried join and other things so far I was unable to produce my desired result.

Any idea how it can be achieved?

Comment: `var string = "123", "456", "789"` is just `var string = "789"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could stringify the elements before joining.

```js
var array = ["123", "456", "789"],
    result = array.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join();
    
console.log(result);
```